# C# IEnumerable Emptied Once Accessed

Tags: c#, .net, umbraco, umbraco8

I'm in the midst of setting up an Umbraco 8 website and have run into some weird behaviour. The project is using .NET 4.7.2.

Basically, I have an IENumerable of type `Event`, a simple list of content that I'd like to render in to a list. However, whenever I do anything with the list (which has items), the list is immediately emptied. This includes simply assigning to a different variable, checking for null etc.

I don't believe this is an Umbraco 8 issue but for clarity, I'm currently running through a Surface Controller and render it by calling the following in my view:

```
@Html.Action("RenderUpcoming", "Events")
```

This is the controller:

```
using Index.Models.Events;
using Index.Models.PublishedContent;
using Papermoon.Umbraco.Kupo.Core.Services.Interfaces;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Umbraco.Web.Mvc;

namespace Index.Web.Controllers.Surface
{
    public class EventsController : SurfaceController
    {
        private readonly KupoGeneralSettings _kupoGeneralSettings;

        public EventsController(IKupoSettingsService kupoSettingsService)
        {
            _kupoGeneralSettings = kupoSettingsService.GetSettings<KupoGeneralSettings>("kupoGeneralSettings");
        }

        public ActionResult RenderUpcoming()
        {
            UpcomingEventsModel model = new UpcomingEventsModel();

            model.Title = "Upcoming Events";

            model.Events = Umbraco.ContentAtXPath("root/homepage/events/event").Select(x => new Event(x));

            model.Events = model.Events.Where(x => x.StartDate > DateTime.Now).OrderBy(x => x.StartDate).Take(3);

            model.TotalEvents = model.Events.Count();

            model.EventListingLink = _kupoGeneralSettings.EventListingLink;

            return PartialView("~/Views/Partials/Events/UpcomingEvents.cshtml", model);
        }
    }
}
```

So here, when I call `model.Events = model.Events.Where(x => x.StartDate > DateTime.Now).OrderBy(x => x.StartDate).Take(3);` - I have results then when I do `model.TotalEvents = model.Events.Count();` the list (model.Events) is then empty.

This also happens when I assign to another variable, when I call `model.Events.Any()`, or when I even do `Model.Events != null`.

It's potentially easier to show this than tell so see the accompanying gif of this happening: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEC77.gif

Thanks,

Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure – you don't know the actual type of the object other than that it's something you can iterate over (an `IEnumerable`).

It could be a generator that returns an infinite stream of things, for instance (well, in this case you know it's not).

If you need a concrete collection, you could use `.ToList()` to cast it into a `List<>` you can certainly iterate over multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

Your `IEnumerable` comes from this call:

`Umbraco.ContentAtXPath("root/homepage/events/event")`

How it is done exactly I do not know since it's Umbraco business, but `IEnuemerable` itself allows "lazy" evaluation. It means that e.g. if you are reading from a SQL database without buffering it will read each time you iterate.

Depending on the data it can return same results or new results (if the data has changed). So what you get in `IEnumerable` depends totally on the implementation details, so if you reiterate you don't know what happens behind the scenes (ranging from nothing special to a new DB query).

To prevent this behavior when the source of `IEnumerable` is unknown you can do `ToList()` at the end of your query:

```
Umbraco.ContentAtXPath("root/homepage/events/event")
   .Select(x => new Event(x))
   .ToList();
```

What will happen is that you iterate through your collection once and add all elements to the list. This list won't change unless you do this yourself.